# Least resources usage browser

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, browser

I'm planning to have a ubuntu server with a kiosk on it that will run a long running program (ran on a browser using lot of JS animations). I want to let the browser/js animations use as much resources as possible, hence I'm looking for a browser that by default uses the least amount of resources. Which browser can you recommend for that task?

Comment: The browser that's used for the webapps in Ubuntu is called [oxide](https://launchpad.net/oxide). Seems pretty lightweight.

Comment: @muru Is it still capable of running a full fledged JS application? Is setting a kiosk with this is the same as with chrome?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I expect so.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out `Midori` it is a lightweight browser, [the description on its website](http://midori-browser.org/about/) says

> Midori is a Web browser that aims to be lightweight and fast. It
>   aligns well with the Xfce philosophy of making the most out of
>   available resources. It has a customizable interface using the GTK+
>   toolkit.

It is still a fully featured browser, so Java script support should not be an issue.

You can find it in the repository

```
sudo apt-get install midori
```

[image]